# How to rotate bone around tail in pose mode?

Tags: animation, bones, pose-mode

I have a monster model that I'm exporting to Unreal Engine. This is why I can't add individual bones or sequences of bones. They should all form a tree. So my model looks like this

[image]

I want to tilt the monster's body left or right. But since the bone can only be rotated around the head, all tentacles move with the body as follows:

[image]

I can achieve my goal with the following steps:

1. Rotation of the bone
2. Move the bone to a position where its tail will have the same coordinates as after rotation.
3. Align the position of all tentacles.

But it's too complicated and the animation will be jerky anyway because I can't line up all the tentacles perfectly.

Is there any solution to achieve my goal in a simpler way?
And for what reason can bones only be rotated around the head?

Answer (score 0):

Bones (aka joints in others softwares), always rotate around their head, if you need another pivot point you simply add a new bone in that location, this is the way they are designed.

There is no problem in adding bones and exporting them to Unreal Engine: the "tree" you're talking about is a simple Parent-child relationship that you can establish in Blender in edit mode.

For a simple setup, select the armature, go to edit mode, add a new bone with its head placed in the point you want to act as pivot, shift select the "head" bone and press Ctr P > Keep Offset to make it child of the head bone, then assign to body vertices some weight to the new bone/vertex group and remove all weight from the head vertex group.

For a better rig you could also make the tentacles child of the new body bone, make the tentacles behave as an IK chain, so taht they react naturally as the body moves, but in this case you will have to bake all animations before exporting to Unreal Engine, so that all IK calculations are transferred as ordinary animation keyframes (there are options for baking in the Pose menu and in the Fbx exporter preferences).